# What is wrong with my code?

Tags: errors, compiling

In a long document I am writing, I wrote

```
$$\left\{ \Gamma_Y: \mathcal{L}_\mathbb{K} (C_\hat{L}(Y)) \longrightarrow \mathcal{L}_\K (C_G(Y), e^{C_G(Y)})) \right\}_\{Y \in X\}$$
```

It does not compile, giving

```
Missing { inserted.
< to be read again >
\gdef 
l.228 ...amma_Y: \mathcal{L}_\mathbb{K} (C_\hat{L}
                                                  (Y)) \longrightarrow \math...
```

I do not understand why it doesn't work, especially because it does work on online compilers.

Comment: Use `C_{\hat{L}}(Y)`. If you have more than one token after the `_` or the `^` you have to surround them with braces: `\mathcal{L}_{\mathbb{K}}`, `C_{\hat{L}}(Y)`.

Comment: It works. Thank you very much, I was going crazy.

Comment: Just curious: Which "online compilers" actually manage to compile this code?

Comment: quicklatex.com

The output is wrong, but it does give something.

Comment: @AnalysisStudent0414 Remember this for the next question: `$$...$$` is obsoleted and depreciated. Good LaTeX.

Comment: What exactly is wrong with it?